# How to make black span width of browser?

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm trying to have the background colour of one post expand the width of the browser but to no avail.

This is the [site](https://michael-thomason-e58y.squarespace.com/blog)

I've tried

```
.content-wrapper, #yui_3_10_1_1_1384098450067_262{
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1200px;
}
```

and

```
.content-wrapper, #yui_3_10_1_1_1384098450067_262{
    background: black;
    position: aboslute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

but that affects the whole post and shifts it to the left.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to add the following to your CSS:

```
body {
margin:0;
}
```

Instead of absolute, use 'relative'. Set your width to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS at the end of your CSS file (or find these rules in your code and amend them to the following):

```
#site {
    padding: 130px 0;
}

#canvas, .content-wrapper {
    max-width: none;
}
```